# How to access values in dictionary

Tags: python

```
import json

x = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "married": True,
  "divorced": False,
  "children": ("Ann","Billy"),
  "pets": None,
  "cars": [
    {"model1": "BMW 230", "mpg": 27.5},
    {"model2": "Ford Edge", "mpg": 24.1}
  ]
}

# use . and a space to separate objects, and a space, a = and a space to separate keys from their values:
#print(json.dumps(x, indent=4, separators=(". ", " = ")))

z = json.dumps(x["model1"], indent=4, separators=(". ", " = "))

print(z)
```

** I am trying to access the key and the associated values from the car models. Can anybody show me how to access the models separately**

Answer (score 0):

Your models are inside the array corresponding to the key of `"cars"`. You can retrieve them like this:

`[car['model1'] for car in  x['cars'] if 'model1' in car.keys()]`

But this only retrieves for the key of `"model1"` in each car dictionary.

If you want all the models, it gets a little more complicated where you have to include to number:

`[car[f'model{i}'] for i, car in enumerate(x['cars'], 1)]`

If your intention is to retrieve the models for each car, you need to have the keys to be the same to make your life easier:

```
import json

x = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "married": True,
  "divorced": False,
  "children": ("Ann","Billy"),
  "pets": None,
  "cars": [
    {"model": "BMW 230", "mpg": 27.5},  # Changed "model1" to "model"
    {"model": "Ford Edge", "mpg": 24.1} # Changed "model2" to "model"
  ]
}
```

With this, you can then simply do:

`[car['model'] for car in x['cars']]`

Answer (score 0):

I am new here but the solution to your problem might be to use the `.get()` method followed by the list indexing for the list element you want to choose and again using the `dictionary` way to get the value if you know the key.

My suggestion is to use this `x.get("cars")[0]["model1"]` in place of `x["model1"]`
This works for python3

Answer (score 0):

I think this is you want
import json

```
x = {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "married": True,
    "divorced": False,
    "children": ("Ann", "Billy"),
    "pets": None,
    "cars": [
        {"model1": "BMW 230", "mpg": 27.5},
        {"model2": "Ford Edge", "mpg": 24.1}
    ]
}

# # use . and a space to separate objects, and a space, a = and a space to separate keys from their values:
# #print(json.dumps(x, indent=4, separators=(". ", " = ")))
newArrayModels = []
for model in x['cars']:
    newModel = ''
    for key in model:
        if key != 'mpg':
            newModel += '{"' + model[key] + '":"'
        else:
            newModel += str(model[key]) + '"}'
    # print(newModel)
    newArrayModels.append(json.loads(newModel))
x['cars'] = newArrayModels
print(json.dumps(x, indent=4, separators=(". ", " = ")))
```